# Turning off peripheral causing unexpected behavior

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Using both Android 4.3/Samsung BLE 2.0 SDK, it is observed that when a peripheral is turned off, the SDK will receive onConnectionStateChange (DEVICE_DISCONNECTED) either immediately or after ~20s delay. From my experience this depends on the peripheral implementation, some of them will tried to report they are being turned off and some just doesn't, so the SDK have to wait for ~20s for the timeout.

To remove this behaviour, I tried to use a Timer to check if I can read a certain characteristic. If the read timed out, I will call disconnect(Android 4.3)/cancelConnection(Samsung) to terminate the connection. The call itself is successful and the onConnectionStateChange callback return a status GATT_SUCCESS. Then I turned the peripheral on and connect to it immediately, discover the services , and encounter problem when I tried to read/write/notify any notification. By using LightBlue in iOS I can confirm that the peripheral is not connected.

After exactly 20s from turning off the peripheral, I will receive a DEVICE_DISCONNECTED callback. I connect again afterwards, and everything operates just fine.

There are two question : 
1. Are we supposed to connect to the peripheral during the 20s delay?
2. Is there any way to get notified when a peripheral is turned off?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Are we supposed to connect to the peripheral during the 20s delay?
   No, It seems from you result itself that OS is doing some actions within the phone to control `DEVICE_CONNECTED` or `DEVICE_DISCONNECTED` events, This may be due to several reasons like device architecture, security reasons or callback itself is delayed to save energy
2. Is there any way to get notified when a peripheral is turned off?
   No I dont think so, The event received for any action is broadcasted so its waiting for a signal from the device it self but its not getting one, the only thing that you can do here is to send it via some other broadcast(or `HTTP` request) from the other end of the device to achieve it

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on what's going on during the 20s delay. It seems not logical that I can call disconnect during the period without receiving error.